# Google search results "plus.google.com" entry

Tags: search-engine, google-plus

I made a Website for a client.

Now when I search for him the result looks like this:

[image]

You can see the fourth entry is somewhat of a special entry and I don't understand where this entry is coming from?

Is this an automated google+ page? I've just created a google places entry but never a google+ page.

How di I get rid of this search result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Places entries show up in Google+ Local. They do not have a Google+ Page associated with them by default, but you can convert your entry to a place to enable more functionality and to hook the entry up with your site by using the [badge code](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/) or the more minimal [direct connect metadata link](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/#connect) to verify your website on the Google+ Local page.

Associating your site with the Google+ Local page, should help with search too and provide people with a method to get directly to your site until the website starts showing up in the search index from being crawled.

Comment: Thank you. So when I add a "Direct connect metadata link". What will happen with the search results? Will the meta-description of the homepage also be displayed in the fourth entry?

Comment: The direct connect tag associates your Google+ page with your website. It will provide a verification mark on your Google+ page profile for the URL to the site. It will also enable search to use your Page's profile pic in the search results alongside entries for your webpage when those start appearing in Google search results.